# ERROR TypeError: this.setNormal is not a function - Angular

Tags: javascript

I am trying to call a function in inside a function by using `this` keyword. But I am getting an error like

```
ERROR TypeError: this.setNormal is not a function
```

So as per my understanding the way I am calling function inside might be cause of the error. Please correct me the approach.

```js
// first function
fun1 (){
    setTimeout(function() {
        this.setNormal();
    }, 2000);
}

// second function
setNormal(){

}
```

Comment: "Scope": https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Scope

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with:

```
// first function
fun1 (){
    setTimeout(function() {
        this.setNormal();
    }, 2000);
}

// second function
setNormal(){

}
```

Is the way you've defined `this` since you are using regular `function(){}` syntax. If you read the specification for `setTimeout`

> Code executed by setTimeout() is called from an execution context
>   separate from the function from which setTimeout was called. The usual
>   rules for setting the this keyword for the called function apply, and
>   if you have not set this in the call or with bind, it will default to
>   the global (or window) object in non–strict mode, or be undefined in
>   strict mode. It will not be the same as the this value for the
>   function that called setTimeout.

I am assuming that you aren't defining `setNormal` in the global scope...hence the problem.

Now, in ES6, lot's of people use `() => {}` function syntax to close over the this in the enclosing scope.

> An arrow function does not have its own this. The this value of the
>   enclosing lexical context is used i.e. Arrow functions follow the
>   normal variable lookup rules. So while searching for this which is not
>   present in current scope they end up finding this from its enclosing
>   scope.

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
setTimeout(function() {
```

to

```
setTimeout(() => {
```

the [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) will allow you to use `this` inside setTimeout callback function (the `this` will point to object outside this function).

Comment: Perfect Thank you.